# How to use LDR with logical shift of #2 in ARM-64?

Tags: assembly, arm64

I am writing a few programs in ARM assembly. 
I wanted to write equivalent of this:

```
int array_test(int index)
{
    ...
    arr[0] = 3;
    arr[1] = 9;
    arr[2] = 6;
    return arr[index];
}
```

where I want to set array values for index 0-2 and return array value at given index.

In my program, I use

**x4 = index; SP, SP#4, SP#8 = arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]; x0 = return value**

To get the array element given by index, I want to multiply index by 4 (for int size) and add to SP. However, when I use

```
LDR x0, [SP, x4, LSL#2]     // Load to x0, (arr[index]) for return;
```

But I get this error with aarch64-linux-android-gcc:

```
error: expected 'lsl' or 'sxtx' with optional shift of #0 or #3
```

However, I am able to get the same with LSL followed by LDR:

```
LSL x4, x4, #2      // multiply index by 4 for 32-bit int
LDR x0, [SP, x4]    // Load to x0, (arr[index]) for return;
```

Why can I not use **LDR** with **LSL** of **#2**? Only #0 or #3 seem to be valid.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used **LDR** instruction with 64-bit destination register instead of 32-bit.

64-bit variant loads eight bytes to destination register **Xn** and allows index shift of **#0** or **#3**

32-bit variant loads four bytes to destination register **Wn** and allows index shift of **#0** or **#2**. Register **Wn** is zero-extended to register **Xn**

You should use `LDR w0, [SP, x4, LSL#2]`

Comment: Thanks! I realized this after going through armasm reference guide.